# Unable to get User details in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, list, javascript, rest, ajax

I am using following code to get user details....

```
function getUsers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

when I debugged it,I found that `response.d` is not defined and response var contains a html tag with numerous script tags in it.
I don't know how to get user details from response var.

Comment: you want to fetch User details from User profile?

Comment: yes i want to fetch User details from User profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code

**Approach 1 :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var userID = <<input your user ID >>
var siteUrl = <<input site url>>

        var soapEnv =
            "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> \
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
  <soap:Body> \
    <GetUserProfileByName xmlns='http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService'> \
      <AccountName>"+userID+"</AccountName> \
    </GetUserProfileByName> \
  </soap:Body> \
</soap:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            url: siteUrl +"_vti_bin/userprofileservice.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            complete: processResult,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
});

function processResult(xData, status) {
         var Dept;
         $(xData.responseXML).find("PropertyData > Name:contains('Department')").each(function() {
            Dept= $(this).parent().find("Values").text();
         alert("Department: "+ Dept);
      });       
}
```

**Approach 2 :**

Add SPServices reference to your code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');

});

function init(){
    var userID = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser();

    var propertyValue = "";    

        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetUserProfileByName",
            async: false,
            AccountName: userID,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

              $(xData.responseXML).find("PropertyData > Name:contains('Department')").each(function() {
                propertyValue = $(this).parent().find("Values").text();

                alert("property Value: "+ propertyValue);
              });
            }
        });
}
```

Try this code which is returning Department for user. You can provide which ever property you need.

Comment: tried the first approch debugged it and found that its not executing this line ` $(xData.responseXML).find("PropertyData > Name:contains('Department')").each(function() {
            Dept= $(this).parent().find("Values").text();`

Comment: i have fetchted user id from clientContext

Comment: explore 'xData.responseXML' in debugger and see if it correct

Comment: both approaches are tested and are working codes

Comment: Second one worked for me ...thanks.....guess i was doing some mistake in first......anyways thank you very much dude